# Where should I ask database-related questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope, site-recommendation

I have a question about Database DDL related to Security. Where should I post it?
My thoughts so far:

- **Posting on Stack Overflow:**

  - A lot of competent users.
  - There are already a lot of database questions asked there.
- **Posting on DBA Stack Exchange:**

  - Probably the right place to ask the question.
  - The site is still in beta, so there are not many active users there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should post it on DBA Stack Exchange even though it's still in Beta, as the reason it's in Beta is because there aren't enough users and questions yet. Support the new sites when possible!

Asking your question there will support that site, and so I would advise posting it there. Besides, it might just get migrated there anyway if you ask it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's not a good reason. Personally I don't care to support some other site I'm not yet involved with and it does have less competence to answer the question. The help center says that "tools often used by software developers" are in-scope - and sql databases are clearly often used by software developers. I wouldn't like to see parts of SO being sliced of into many different pieces because people vote sites into existence that overlap with SO's scope.

Comment: Yikes, terrible comment. That way no part of IT can be "sliced off" from any other. Nowadays we also have experts at [security.se] and their cryptography related questions generally go to [crypto.se], to name just two slices.